# Xamarin Prism.Unity.Forms 7.0.0.396 give error on update from version 6.3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-7

Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll'
  at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters)

Can you please suggest for solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message tells you everything you need to know: `Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0`. You have a reference to v4.0 of Unity. Prism 7 references v5.0. You need to check your dependencies as somewhere you have a reference to the old package.

Also note that due to some changes that were made in the way that Unity ships, Prism has also made a change from referencing the Unity package to the Unity.Container package as of Prism 7.1.